# WPF: Trying to add a class to Window.Resources Again

Tags: wpf

I did exactly the same thing, but still the same error is occurring: "The tag 'CenterToolTipConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly=WpfApplication1'. Line 12 Position 10."

**CenterToolTipConverter.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class CenterToolTipConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.FirstOrDefault(v => v == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) != null)
            {
                return double.NaN;
            }
            double placementTargetWidth = (double)values[0];
            double toolTipWidth = (double)values[1];
            return (placementTargetWidth / 2.0) - (toolTipWidth / 2.0);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly=WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CenterToolTipConverter x:Key="myCenterToolTipConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is MainWindow.xaml in the assembly WpfApplication1? If so, just use `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove assembly part if you are referring to the same assembly.

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

> Or

```
 xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly="
```

> **From Msdn :** assembly can be omitted if the clr-namespace referenced is being defined within the same assembly as the application code that is referencing the custom classes. Or, an equivalent syntax for this case is to specify assembly=, with no string token following the equals sign.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But now I have another problem. When I make a reference to this method on a resource of styles, it gives the message "The resource can not be resolved".

Comment: @user3952846 different problem means you should ask a different question. **But first search to make sure your question hasn't been answered already.**

Comment: @clcto thanks for replying i was wondering what i should reply to this comment, though i wasnt sure whats the new problem is. :)