# Accessing a user class method

Tags: wpf, styles

I did the following question, which has already been answered,

[WPF: Trying to add a class to Window.Resources Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371975/wpf-trying-to-add-a-class-to-window-resources-again)

but there was another problem: when I try to access the "CenterToolTipConverter" method  through a resource for styles, the message occurs: "The resource can not be resolved"

**CenterToolTipConverter.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class CenterToolTipConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.FirstOrDefault(v => v == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) != null)
            {
                return double.NaN;
            }
            double placementTargetWidth = (double)values[0];
            double toolTipWidth = (double)values[1];
            return (placementTargetWidth / 2.0) - (toolTipWidth / 2.0);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly=WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CenterToolTipConverter x:Key="myCenterToolTipConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Until here, no problem. However, when I try to access the "CenterToolTipConverter" method, in:

**Styles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myCenterToolTipConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="PlacementTarget.ActualWidth"/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

That message error occours ("The resource can not be resolved"). What is wrong here? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the converter as resource in the `Window`, but the `ResourceDictionary` has no knowledge of the resources defined in the `Window`.

Either define the converter in the `ResourceDictionary` or add both resources on application level to the `App.xaml.`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did this, but got the error:

Comment: Continuing: got the error

Exception:Thrown: "A System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was thrown: "'The value provided in'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' has thrown a exception.

Comment: @user3952846 Hmm, I don't get that error. The converter and style work when I add them to a new project (except that the tooltip doesn't center)

Comment: Thanks, Roel, I'll search a little more.